# Grouping several SVG's into one object

Tags: svg

I'm trying to reuse an SVG sprite icone into new SVG object.
The new object is just a circle that contains the icon from the sprite.
I understand that I need to use the defs tag to group some shapes together,
But i have have a problem referencing my sprite icone inside the defs tag.

sprite:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
<symbol id="icon_1" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
  <path d="M10.6 29.3h14.5V44H10.6z" class="st0"/>
  <path d="M25 29.3h14.5V44H25zm-7.2-14.7h14.5v14.7H17.8zm0 0l3.9-4m10.6 4l3.9-4m-3.9 18l3.9-3.7m-25.6 4.4l4.3-4.4m24.6 4.7l3.9-4M39.5 44l3.9-4M21.2 10.6h15M14.5 24.9h3.3m17.7.6h7.9M36.2 10v15.5m7.2.1V40" class="st0"/>
</symbol >
```

new object:

```
<svg><defs>
<g id="shape">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="rgba(124,240,10,0.5)" />
    <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#icon_1"></image>
</g>
```

I read that i can use image tags to reference SVG elements.
obviously i'm doing something wrong.
Basically the expected result should be a stroked circle with the icon inside
in a way that I will be able to animate the entire object

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  Your main problem was that you were careless with your opening and closing tags.

Your second SVG had a stray opening `<defs>` element, which meant that the `<g id="shape">` element was left inside the `<defs>` section.  `<defs>` is for defining elements to be re-used later, and anything in a `<defs>` will only be drawn when referenced from elsewhere.

There were a couple of other problems.

1. You can't use an `<image>` to reference a symbol. You will need to use a `<use>` for that.
2. You will need to supply a `width` and `height` so that the symbol gets draw at an appropriate size.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon_1" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
      <path d="M10.6 29.3h14.5V44H10.6z" class="st0"/>
      <path d="M25 29.3h14.5V44H25zm-7.2-14.7h14.5v14.7H17.8zm0 0l3.9-4m10.6 4l3.9-4m-3.9 18l3.9-3.7m-25.6 4.4l4.3-4.4m24.6 4.7l3.9-4M39.5 44l3.9-4M21.2 10.6h15M14.5 24.9h3.3m17.7.6h7.9M36.2 10v15.5m7.2.1V40" class="st0"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
new object:

<svg>
  <g id="shape">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="rgba(124,240,10,0.5)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="#icon_1"></use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Do i need the https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody? to support IE-9,10?

Comment: IE9 supports SVG content.

Comment: could you please take a look at this question when you find the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980870/animate-an-svg-object-that-uses-svg-sprite-icon, its related to this one.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) tag is designed to be used with complete images, not fractions.  I guess that [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) is the right tag for your use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1">
  <symbol id="icon_1" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
    <path d="M10.6 29.3h14.5V44H10.6z" class="st0"/>
    <path d="M25 29.3h14.5V44H25zm-7.2-14.7h14.5v14.7H17.8zm0 0l3.9-4m10.6 4l3.9-4m-3.9 18l3.9-3.7m-25.6 4.4l4.3-4.4m24.6 4.7l3.9-4M39.5 44l3.9-4M21.2 10.6h15M14.5 24.9h3.3m17.7.6h7.9M36.2 10v15.5m7.2.1V40" class="st0"/>
  </symbol>
  <defs>
     <g id="shape">
      <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="rgba(124,240,10,0.5)" />
      <use x="2" y="-3" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="#icon_1"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#shape"/>
</svg>
```

Also, if the sprite is in a separate file, you have to reference the symbol within that file: `<use hlink:href="sprites.svg#icon1"/>`.

Comment: From the SVG spec: "The ‘image’ element can refer to raster image files such as PNG or JPEG or to files with MIME type of "image/svg+xml"."

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Whops, you are right. Fixed, and thanks for the pointer.